# As Arsonist, how do I prevent lighting myself on fire if another Arsonist doused me?

Tags: town-of-salem

OK, so in an All Any or Custom game (Rainbow in particular), you can have more than one Arsonist.

If a different Arsonist douses you and you light up all doused victims, you yourself will die.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't actually documented in the game, but yes there is.

As an Arsonist, if you choose to not do anything for a night, you will clean the gas off your house if there is any.

I highly recommend doing this the night after you get doused so the other Arsonist can't accidentally light you on fire the next night.

Comment: On a side note, as an Arsonist, you *can* win with other Arsonists.

Answer (score 0):

If one arsonist (1) douses a target and the other arsonists (2) ignites (the same night), it will kill the arsonist (1)'s target BUT ONLY IF 2 IGNITES AFTER 1 DOUSES.

If arso1 douses A B C D and douses E on the 5th night, arso2 will kill A B C D, but he will only also kill E if he presses the ignite button after the arsonist number 1.

In other words, my answer to your question would be to Hit ignite straight away before he can click you... it won't kill his target (you) then.